# How configure logging for Flyway command line

Tags: logging, flyway

Here on my job we started the use of flyway and the databases admins asked to me if the flyway has a log. After read some articles on internet and on documentation of the flyway, I did not find a way to do this configuration.

Here on StackOverflow some users say that only is necessary put the log4j on classpath and it should work. I tried put log4j files but does not work for me, however when I tried put the files of SLF4J on lib directory of flyway (classpath):

- slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
- slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar
- simplelogger.properties.

The output of flyway has changed inserting logging prefixes:

---

> C:\dev\flyway-4.0.3>flyway -configFile=C:/dev/repos\flyway/ad/DT/flyway.conf/flyway.conf info -q
>   [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.VersionPrinter - Flyway 4.0.3 by Boxfuse
>   [main] INFO org.flywaydb.commandline.Main -
>   [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory - Database: jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxxxxxx\sql2008:1437;authentication=NotSpecified;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStat
>   es=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;TransparentNetworkIPResolution=true;serverNameAsACE=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptiv
>   e;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=TST_FLYWAY;columnEncryptionSetting=Disabled;appl
>   icationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite; (Microsoft SQL Server 10.50)
>   [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.sqlserver.SQLServerDbSupport - SQLServer does not support setting the schema for the current session. Default schema NOT changed to [flyway]
>   [main] INFO org.flywaydb.commandline.Main -
>
> ---

But no file was created on the directory that I configured on **simplelogger.properties** file:

> org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=C:/dev/flyway-4.0.3/log/flyway.log

What I should do to configure the log?

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using slf4j and logback** 
where to add the file (you can use simplelogger also but logback is better)

```
  C: \ flyway - 4.0.3
 ├─ conf
 │ logback.xml
 └ ─ lib
        Logback-classic-1.1.7.jar
        Logback-core-1.1.7.jar
        Slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
```

**Logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <property scope="context" name="LOG_DIR" value="logs" />

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p : %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/flyway.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/flyway.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p : %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

**Modify flyway.cmd**

```
%JAVA_CMD% -cp "%INSTALLDIR%\conf;%INSTALLDIR%\lib\*;%INSTALLDIR%\drivers\*" org.flywaydb.commandline.Main %*
```